# Scrollable off canvas menu

Tags: css, html

I just found an interesting off-canvas menu on codepen. If someone clicks the hamburger icon, it shows overlay menu with its content. But that overlay menu couldn't scroll down at all. If someone scrolls down, the page behind is scrolling; not the overlay menu. I need to scroll down that overlay page. I checked the code and and found the problem. It uses `overflow:hidden` for that wrapper div. I set `overflow: auto` to that div; seems problem solved. But background page is still scrolling down with overlay menu. How can I set only overlay menu to be scrolled down?

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: $color-main;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the link for [codepen](https://codepen.io/KingKabir/pen/QyPwgG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `overflow:scroll;` at overlay class then add more links to menu. it will scroll.

for page scroll, change the jquery like this

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

that will make body non-scrollable when menu clicked.

Comment: When I click hamburger icon using this script, menu didn't work.

Comment: It works because the body content is very low. Try adding more content to body (not list items) and see.

Comment: Sorry the link was wrong..i changed it https://codepen.io/tsdln/pen/BZBOxQ

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Comment: But there is a problem. When we close that overlay menu, it took back to normal page but it can't scroll.

Comment: add a class like `.overlayhidden{ overflow:hidden;}` to your css then edit js like this  `$('body').toggleClass('overlayhidden');`

https://codepen.io/tsdln/pen/BZBOxQ